# I am unable to find transformation between two points using cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts)

Tags: python, rgb, transformation, opencv, infrared

I am unable to find a transformation between two points using `cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts1)` where `pts1` and `pts2` are 68 facial landmarks individually. I got the following error.

```
Cell In[36], line 4
    M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(p1ts,pts2)

error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp:3522: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.checkVector(2, CV_32F) == 4 && dst.checkVector(2, CV_32F) == 4 in function 'cv::getPerspectiveTransform'
```

When I use 4 points in `pts1` and `pts2`, it works fine.

Comment: The function expects four points.